# How to make an argument show up a certain amount of times Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code for concatenating two arrays:

```py
trainPredict = np.c_[trainPredict, np.zeros(trainPredict.shape)]
```

But depending on a number, lets say `n`, I need the zeros array to show up multiple times, such as if `n=2`:

```py
trainPredict = np.c_[trainPredict, np.zeros(trainPredict.shape), np.zeros(trainPredict.shape)]
```

That code works when I have `n=2`, but I need a way to automate this so that depending on what `n` is I don't need to manually add arguments.

I tried using a for loop in something like this:

```py
for i in range(0,n):
    trainPredict = np.c_[trainPredict, np.zeros(trainPredict.shape)]
```

but it does not work, and I'm very new with python so I'm not sure what is going on here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not the most efficient code, but it should work. What do you mean by _"but it does not work"_? Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a `list-comprehension` and unpack the zeros array in the main one

```
trainPredict = np.c_[trainPredict, *[np.zeros(trainPredict.shape) for _ in range(n)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
arr = np.zeros(trainPredict.shape)
list_.append(arr)
list_ = [arr] * n
newTrainPredict = np.array(list_)
newTrainPredict = newTrainPredict.reshape(trainPredict.shape[0], trainPredict.shape[0] * n)
```